# Best Library for Real-Time Javascript Game with PHP Backend

Tags: php, real-time, javascript, multiplayer

I'm currently in the planning stages for a real-time multiplayer game that would be built using Javascript at the frontend and PHP on the backend and I'm just wondering if anyone here knows of any good libraries for such a game?

Comment: Real time with PHP backend? Why not take a look a Node.js, it works really great for such things plus you could reuse code and save a lot of context switching when doing both frontend and backend code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Socket.IO](http://socket.io) might be useful. Although will only be useful for the two browsers that support WebSockets.

> Socket.IO aims to make realtime apps
>   possible in every browser and mobile
>   device, blurring the differences
>   between the different transport
>   mechanisms.

Comment: I'd second Ivo Wetzel with node.js. Louis suggested Socket.IO - this is what I use and it's a breath of fresh air. It uses HTML5 websockets but will fall back to Flash, XHR-polling, etc. if not available. Socket.IO/Socket.IO-node is one of the most exciting projects out there at the moment.

Comment: Socket.IO is great, but keep in my that everything besides WebSockets and Flash fall backs is just *bad* for real time. I'm using a fall back myself in one of my projects(http://bonsaiden.github.com/NodeGame-Shooter/) and after a couple of minutes the flash thing gets *quite* laggy. Although it's not the same one that Socket.IO uses, the Flash/JS communication adds around another 30ms of latency.

Comment: I've been using [gimite's](http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) Flash WebSocket fallback with good results for realtime games. I agree that other forms of fallback Socket.IO provides will be quite unsuitable for fast action games.

Comment: If you find `socket.io` too slow, you can use a pure websocket library like [Einaros ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws). See [10+ tips for optimizing websockets bandwidth usage in HTML5 games](http://rezoner.net/optimizing-websockets-bandwidth-usage-in-html5-games,299)